# Using "excited" or "exciting": "The movie was excited/exciting"

Tags: grammar, word-choice

> The movie was **excited**.

vs.

> The movie was **exciting**.

What situation we need to use "-ed" or  "-ing"?

Answer (score 1):

It's passive (be excited) vs. adjective (exciting).

> The movie was **exciting**. Those who watched it were **excited**.

Answer (score 0):

Excited refers usually to a person or their mood

> That got me excited!

Exciting refers to an event or action being exciting and making a person excited, an object, in this case movie, cannot be excited because only a living thing can be excited

> That movie was exciting!